# Error: Invalid parameter boot_disk_type puppet

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am automating the disks in google cloud platform and using puppet for that. 
But the older parameters of adding disk on instances are not working. Do you have any idea as I am pasting an error message :

```
Error: Invalid parameter boot_disk_type on Gce_instance[new-instance] at /etc/puppet/manifests/gce.pp:9 on node automation
```

Here's the output of my manifest:

```
gce_instance { 'new-instance':
ensure                => present,
machine_type          => 'g1-small',
zone                  => 'us-central1-a',
network               => 'default',
tags                  => ['apache', 'web'],
image                 => 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20150710',
modules      => ['puppetlabs-apache', 'puppetlabs-stdlib',]
boot_disk_type   => 'pd-ssd',
size_gb          => '50',
}
```

Comment: What is the `.pp` file that you're using? Can you paste `/etc/puppet/manifests/gce.pp` here?

Comment: Hey,

I've pasted the output on gce.pp file above.

Answer (score 1):

On the README for [puppetlabs/puppetlabs-gce_compute](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-gce_compute), which appears to be the Puppet library you're using, there is no `boot_disk_type` attribute. There is, however, a `boot_disk` attribute. Try using that instead.